# Git return "Permission Denied" when trying to add files

Tags: git, macos, terminal, file-permissions

I recently bought a new mac, and have been cloning my repositories to it. I made a change to one of them, and tried to run `git add --all`, and was pretty surprised when git returned. [...] being the path to the repo locally.
`fatal: Unable to create '[...]/.git/index.lock': Permission denied`

I pretty sure I ran git clone as the user that i'm currently logged in as.

Can someone tell me why this happened? why do i now have permission to the .git/index.lock file?

Comment: Noop. Said question was caused by a duplicate file. This was caused by incorrect permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was wrong, seems I ran `git clone` with `sudo`.  Removing the repository and cloning it again fixed the problem.